# Apache always returning js as text/plain

Tags: apache, mime-types

I have an Apache install which always returns .js files as `text/plain`.

I've disabled **mod_negotioation**, and checked the MIME is set in `/etc/mime.types`. I know this is the correct file, as I added `application/font-woff`, which is working as expected.

I've also disabled **mod_pagespeed**, and renamed `/etc/apache2/magic` to `/etc/apache2/magic.disabled`, even though **mod_mime_magic** isn't enabled.

Even adding `AddType application/javascript .js` to the `.htaccess` results in the same text/plain.

Where else can I force the type to be set?

Answer (score 0):

Use the other [JavaScript mime types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329#section-7):

```
AddType application/x-javascript .js
#AddType application/x-ecmascript .js
#AddType application/ecmascript .js
#AddType text/javascript .js
#AddType text/ecmascript .js
```

Try one at a time until you find a match.

**References**

- [RFC 4329: Scripting Media Types](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4329)
- [Reducing MIME type security risks (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941)