# Error regarding "Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"."

Tags: javascript, html, angular, apache, mime-types

I'm hosting my angular app on my local Apache server. Everything works fine but when I reload the page with the url `http://localhost/TimeSheet/project_component/1` I get the below errors. The page loads just fine when I first go to that page, errors pop up only on refresh.

[image: The Errors I am getting]

I believe the issues can be because of how I'm routing to that specific page but I'm not really sure why exactly. I know it's because it was trying to find that module/file but an error was returned, hence the mime type "text/html", but why doesn't that happen when the page first loads.

Any help is appreciated, let me know if you need to see the code or require more info.

Comment: Make sure you have configured your mimes for javascript, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007309/apache-always-returning-js-as-text-plain